# Laravel Reverb: Pusher error: Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.2.0"

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-reverb

#### Reverb Version

v1.0.0-beta4

#### Laravel Version

v11.0.7

#### PHP Version

8.2.16

#### Description

I have Laravel reverb served in a subdomain on my server. Now I have connected to that subdomain from local with laravel-echo and there is no problem in eco connection.

But when I try to fire an event from the back-end I keep getting this error "Pusher error: Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.2.0" ". But I can't understand why it is showing.

- The error message
  (https://flareapp.io/share/17DxbD97)
- my reveb connection .env
  [image]
- server reverb console
  [image]

But when I am locally using an application as a socket only and firing events from another application then everything is working fine only when I deploy reverb on the server there is a problem.

- Local Reverb console
  [image]

My concept is that there will be a reverb server in a subdomain and everyone will connect to that reverb server subdomain from another domain.

Comment: check you composer.json file and check php version there

Comment: Which PHP version are you actually running? Please share all details **in text form**

Comment: I tried changing to PHP 8.2 and 8.3 and each time I got the same error

Comment: How did you check which version you were really running? Can you share the full and exact error message in text form?

Comment: After changing Litespeed

Server Configuration > External App>Command
```
lsphp74/bin/lsphp

# To 

lsphp83/bin/lsphp

```
It's works for me .. Thanks for your help